# How to get Subtype name in Field using field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I would like to get feature subtype name in another field using field calculator.

Any one can advise to make this success?

I am expecting ".Cal" file code using with Field calculator.

Comment: does this solution help ? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91651/transfer-subtype-descriptions-form-long-integer-value-into-a-string-at-new-diffr

Comment: Is there anything help with Field caluclator is better.

Comment: I am not aware of a technique that you could use to do this with Field Calculator, but am always happy to be enlightened if there is, which is why I proposed that this question be made a duplicate of one that proposed what seems to me to be the best way to achieve the same result.